# Sybase - SAP ASE - replication server: routing declaration

Tags: replication, sap, sybase

I'm trying to declare a routing in SAP Replication Server.

I have:

A server (let's call it S1) with ASE and RS server (let's call it RS1).

A server (let's call it S2) with ASE and RS server (let's call it RS2).

A server (let's call it S3) with ASE server.

I have A replication in RS1 from database in S1 to databases in S1 and S2.

Now I'm trying to add a replication to a database in S3 via RS2: a routing from RS1 to RS2 and a subscription to the DB in S3.

I declared the routing, an agent between the 2 RSSDs.

When I'm trying to set the subscription (in RS2) to the databse in S3 I've got an error - saying that it doesn't know the replication definition.

Anyone familiar with routing declaration?

Thanks.

Comment: it's a bit hard to understand your setup, and what you're looking for, with the use of non-standard terms; please list the primary-dataserver/primary-database pairs (PDS/PDB), replicate-dataserver/replicate-database pairs (RDS/RDB), which repserver manages each dataserver/database, which PDS/PDS pairs have a repdef (and type of repdef - MSA? table-level? or is this a WarmStandby setup?), which RDS/RDB has a subscription, and last but not least, the command you're issuing that's generating the error plus the complete/actual error you're getting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: I resolve it.

Especially what I did was arrange the settings and delete duplicates. Then I set up the connections again, and then the subscription.

- drop connections.
- Drop route.
- Purge route - clean up any old references that were created with the failed create route.
- suspend connection.
- Stop rep agent and ran the rs_zeroltm to tell the rep agent to start at the end of the log and restarted the rep agent.
- resume connection
- re-created the route between the RSSDs.
- verify the replication definitions were copied to the target RSSD
- create a subscription
- resume the replicate connection on the second RS

Thanks.